# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) after deployment JROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, tomcat8, warbler, ahoy

Ror Experts,

I am having some kind of routing issue (I think so..). The Ahoy tracks visits and events in the development environment - running under webbrick server. When the application is deployed using warbler and published to apache tomcat server, it throws 500 error, Wrong number of Arguments (given 0, expected 1) while trying to log events. Tracking visits works as expected.

I have already tried suggestions mentioned in ahoy github account (https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/issues/356) without success.

I tried to debug if the data from react code is sending data as expected. It is indeed sending the data. I tried to post the data using postman directly to the controller using the same load to both development and deployed environment. It works on development but not on deployed.

I also tried to check error logs on the server. There is no information except 500 error.

Can someone help me out...

***PS:***

**Prod server:** Apache Tomcat

**Environment:** Jruby on rails

**Front End:** React

Comment: There is some action in your app that is expecting something which is either not used in development or is ok but on deployment it goes as nil and the code crashes. Logs will be mentioning the line. Don't you have access to error logs on your server? If you can paste...

Comment: The error 500 means internal server error which means something crashed anywhere in the backend code. So you need to see those internal server logs man!

Comment: Thanks. This is all I see org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log DEBUG: resetting rack response due exception

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Fixed using gem as integral part of application instead of gem...... Still doesn't know what caused the issue. My gut feeling is some kind of routing issue with jruby and bundler warbler.